# How to use part of composite key in JPA repository methods?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a class with embedded Id

```
@Entity
@Table(name="account_table")
Public class AccountLink {

@EmbeddedId
private AccountLinkKey accountLinkKey;
//Rest of code
}

@Embeddable
Public class AccountLinkKey {
//Rest code here

@ColumnName(name="i am hiding")
private String segAccount;

@ColumnName(name="i am hiding")
private String secAccount;
//Rest of code
}
```

Now in my repository I want to have a method to search only by `secAccount`, so how should I write `findBy..`

```
List<AccountLink> findBy...(String secAccount);
```

I tried `findByAccountLinkKeySecAccount(String secAccount)` but still no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have rewritten your class and could add repository function as well. Here's my implementation which you might consider taking a look at.

Here's the class `AccountLink.java`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account_table")
public class AccountLink {

    @Column(name = "id")
    public Long id;

    @EmbeddedId
    private AccountLinkKey accountLinkKey;

    @Embeddable
    public class AccountLinkKey {
        @Column(name = "seg_account")
        private String segAccount;

        @Column(name = "sec_account")
        private String secAccount;
    }
}
```

And the `AccountLinkRepository.java`.

```
public interface AccountLinkRepository extends JpaRepository<AccountLink, Long> {
    AccountLink findAccountLinkByAccountLinkKey_SecAccount(String secAccount);
}
```

I have added an `id` column in the `AccountLink` class as the primary key of the `account_table`. You might need something like this as well for your table.

Comment: Thanks for the help ... your answer pointed out the issue i have to just add an underscore to my code. Strange thing was that similar thing is working without underscore at other places... :(

Answer (score 6):

I used this example: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-embedded-method-parameters

**You define the Composite Key Class for the id:**

```
@Embeddable
public class BookId implements Serializable {

    private String author;
    private String name;

    // standard getters and setters
}
```

**You use it as id in your entity:**

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @EmbeddedId
    private BookId id;
    private String genre;
    private Integer price;

    //standard getters and setters
}
```

**You finally make your calls to the repository:**

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, BookId> {

    List<Book> findByIdName(String name);

    List<Book> findByIdAuthor(String author);
}
```

Example of code where I used it: [Quiz Engine with JetBrainsAcademy](https://github.com/vinny59200/JBAQuizEngineWithCompositeKey/blob/master/src/engine/vv/model/VVQuiz.java)

Answer (score 1):

Normally when you want to perform some action on embedded columns in JPA,You bind your columns with underscore('_').

Example :

```
findBy<Entity_Class_Column_Name>_<Embaded_Class_Column_Name>(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's useful when we used for delete method for `@Embeded` for keys with `@Entity`.

1. Your keys should append '_' with the variable of Embeddable class.
   example: pkId_firstName (pkid is key of @Embeded and firstName is from Embedded class variable.)
2. it should traverse with keys to a variable with 'underscore symbol. since without '_' underscore it does not work.